# How to filter a multidimensional array in Rust?

Tags: rust, multidimensional-array, serde

I have the JSON data below and I need to parse it using Rust. Using serde, I can access some of the JSON as such:

```rust
let v: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("Unable to parse");
let sessions = v["data"]["sessions"].as_array().unwrap();
let programs = v["data"]["programs"].as_array().unwrap();
```

But how do I filter for a single `programData` array item using the `programs.id` value? I'm trying something like this but I can't get it right:

```rust
    for x in programs {
            let programId = &x["id"];

            // not working - produces 'no implementation' error while building
            let programSessions = sessions.iter().filter(|&f| f["programData"].as_array().unwrap()["programRefId"] == programId).collect();
        }
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "name": "my name",
    "sessions": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "programData": [
          {
            "dataPhase": 1,
            "programRefId": 2,
            "programSpecificData": {
              "completed": false
            }
          },
          {
            "dataPhase": 2,
            "programRefId": 3,
            "programSpecificData": {
              "completed": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "programs": [
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put *"not working"* in technical terms. Does it produce a compile time or runtime error? Does it produce an output different from what you expect?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I made edits to describe the error in more detail but I'm not even sure how to write that line of code to work. Also, all `id` values are integers, I don't know why some were encased in quotes.

Comment: Please add the complete error message, not just an excerpt from your IDE (use `cargo build` or similar).

Comment: JSON updated; it is formatted / validated on https://jsonformatter.org now :)

Comment: There are multiple `"programRefId"`s in each array of `"programData"` which one do you think or want `f["programData"].as_array().unwrap()["programRefId"]` to select?

Comment: Correct, in this example I would want `programRefId` = 3. Overall, I'm looking to iterate through `programs`, pull the `id` value for each program and then use that value to obtain the `programRefId` in `sessions.programData`

Comment: How is Rust supposed to know which of the many `programData` entries has `programRefId` = 3 without you iterating over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna filter for a single `programData` array item using `program.id` you need to change a couple things. Looks like you're directly comparing a `serde_json::Value` with anothoer `serde_json::Value` within a nested structure which can lead to issues. You're also trying to filer on `programData` as if it's a single object when it's actually an array.

You should loop through each program, then for each program loop through each session then in each session filter `programData` itemas based on `programRefId`.

```rust
use serde_json::Value;

fn main() {
    let data = r#"
    {
        "data": {
            "name": "my name",
            "sessions": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "programData": [
                        {
                            "dataPhase": 1,
                            "programRefId": 2,
                            "programSpecificData": {
                                "completed": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "dataPhase": 2,
                            "programRefId": 3,
                            "programSpecificData": {
                                "completed": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "programs": [
                {
                    "id": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    "#;

    let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(data).expect("Unable to parse");
    let sessions = v["data"]["sessions"].as_array().unwrap();
    let programs = v["data"]["programs"].as_array().unwrap();

    for program in programs {
        let program_id = program["id"].as_i64().unwrap(); // Assuming id is always an integer.

        for session in sessions {
            let program_data = session["programData"].as_array().unwrap();

            let program_sessions: Vec<&Value> = program_data.iter().filter(|&f| {
                // Assuming programRefId is always present and an integer.
                f["programRefId"].as_i64() == Some(program_id)
            }).collect();

            // Now you have the filtered programSessions for the current program_id
            // Do something with program_sessions...
            println!("Filtered program sessions for program id {}: {:?}", program_id, program_sessions);
        }
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use%20serde_json%3A%3AValue%3B%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20r%23%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22data%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22my%20name%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sessions%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22programData%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dataPhase%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22programRefId%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22programSpecificData%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22completed%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dataPhase%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22programRefId%22%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22programSpecificData%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22completed%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22programs%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%22%23%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20v%3A%20Value%20%3D%20serde_json%3A%3Afrom_str%28data%29.expect%28%22Unable%20to%20parse%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20sessions%20%3D%20v%5B%22data%22%5D%5B%22sessions%22%5D.as_array%28%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20programs%20%3D%20v%5B%22data%22%5D%5B%22programs%22%5D.as_array%28%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20program%20in%20programs%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20program_id%20%3D%20program%5B%22id%22%5D.as_i64%28%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Assuming%20id%20is%20always%20an%20integer.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20session%20in%20sessions%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20program_data%20%3D%20session%5B%22programData%22%5D.as_array%28%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20program_sessions%3A%20Vec%3C%26Value%3E%20%3D%20program_data.iter%28%29.filter%28%7C%26f%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Assuming%20programRefId%20is%20always%20present%20and%20an%20integer.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%5B%22programRefId%22%5D.as_i64%28%29%20%3D%3D%20Some%28program_id%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29.collect%28%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Now%20you%20have%20the%20filtered%20programSessions%20for%20the%20current%20program_id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20something%20with%20program_sessions...%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println%21%28%22Filtered%20program%20sessions%20for%20program%20id%20%7B%7D%3A%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20program_id%2C%20program_sessions%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

`Filtered program sessions for program id 3: [Object {"dataPhase": Number(2), "programRefId": Number(3), "programSpecificData": Object {"completed": Bool(true)}}]`

Comment: This works well, thank you for explaining your approach and the inline comments